# HuggingFace transformers - encoding long input with context

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am using a BERT like model, which has a limit for input's length.
I am looking to encode a long input and feed into BERT.
Most common solution I know of is sliding-window to add context to input's segments.

For example:

```
model_max_size = 5
stride = 2

input = [1, ..., 12]

output = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], -> [6, 7, 8]
  [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], -> [9, 10, 11]
  [10, 11, 12] -> [12]
]
```

Is there a known good strategy?
Do you send each input into consecutive windows and average their outputs?
Any already built in implementation for this?

HuggingFace tokenizer has the stride and return_overflowing_tokens feature but it's not quite it as it works only for the first sliding window.

*I know there are other models accepting longer input (e.g. LongFormer, BigBird etc.) but I need to use this specific one.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no general answer to this. It depends on your task.